# How to read Firebase Database from Firebase Web Hosting?

Tags: html, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I am new in Firebase Hosting and I would like to read data from the web. My database in Firebase looks like this:

```
{
  "contactos" : {
    "-MGcSVviK2nxd52KNtZ" : {
      "email" : "david@hotmail.com",
      "fecha" : 1599480318009,
      "nombre" : "David R",
    },
    "-RTcnLta8ud8Dw168oLS" : {
      "email" : "roger@hotmail.com",
      "fecha" : 1599486127716,
      "nombre" : "Roger H",
    }
  }
}
```

I installed Firebase tools and initializesd the project which created an index.html file that warned me that the configuration was successful ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      body { background: #ECEFF1; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87); font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #message { background: white; max-width: 360px; margin: 100px auto 16px; padding: 32px 24px; border-radius: 3px; }
      #message h2 { color: #ffa100; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 8px; }
      #message h1 { font-size: 22px; font-weight: 300; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); margin: 0 0 16px;}
      #message p { line-height: 140%; margin: 16px 0 24px; font-size: 14px; }
      #message a { display: block; text-align: center; background: #039be5; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: white; padding: 16px; border-radius: 4px; }
      #message, #message a { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24); }
      #load { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); text-align: center; font-size: 13px; }
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body, #message { margin-top: 0; background: white; box-shadow: none; }
        body { border-top: 16px solid #ffa100; }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <h1>Firebase Hosting Setup Complete</h1>
      <p>You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!</p>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/">Open Hosting Documentation</a>
    </div>
    <p id="load">Firebase SDK Loading&hellip;</p>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const loadEl = document.querySelector('#load');
        // // 
        // // The Firebase SDK is initialized and available here!
        //
        // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { });
        // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
        // firebase.firestore().doc('/foo/bar').get().then(() => { });
        // firebase.functions().httpsCallable('yourFunction')().then(() => { });
        // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
        // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
        // firebase.analytics(); // call to activate
        // firebase.analytics().logEvent('tutorial_completed');
        // firebase.performance(); // call to activate
        //
        // // 

        try {
          let app = firebase.app();
          let features = [
            'auth', 
            'database', 
            'firestore',
            'functions',
            'messaging', 
            'storage', 
            'analytics', 
            'remoteConfig',
            'performance',
          ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
          loadEl.textContent = `Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`;
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          loadEl.textContent = 'Error loading the Firebase SDK, check the console.';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is that in a url type

`https://defaultname.web.app/-MGcSVviK2nxd52KNtZ` or

`https://defaultname.web.app/contactos?id=-MGcSVviK2nxd52KNtZ`

anybody can read the basic data within linked to this object, in this case:

**Email** david@hotmail.com

**Date** 1599480318009

**Name** David R

My basic questions are: Do I need to use Java Script? **How can I write the file to read in Firebase and display in html?** How to use the parameter in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to execute Javascript to setup routes for your application in order to do that

You can create a router to handle this for you.

Take a deep look into the following:

```
const ContactosComponent = {
  render: async() => {
    // imagine location.pathname being equal to /contactos/<id>
    const contactoId = location.pathname.split('/').pop()
    // retrieve contacto info
    const contacto = (await firebase.firestore().collection('contactos').doc(contactoId).get()).data()

    return `<span> Hello ${contacto.nombre}</span>`
  }
}

// here you declare the routes of your application
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/contactos',
    component: ContactosComponent
  }
]

// a function to find the specific route that your user requests
const findComponentByPath = (path) => routes.find(r => r.path.match(new RegExp(`^\\${path}$`, 'gm')))

const redirectTo = async (path) => {
  console.log('path', path)
  const { component /* = ErrorComponent */ } = findComponentByPath(path) || {}
  console.log('component', component)
  // ATTENTION: you need to have a div with this id into your html
  document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = await component.render()
}

const router = () => {
  const path = location.pathname
  redirectTo(path)
}
```

Then you would track your route changes and send them to the router, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', router)
  window.addEventListener('load', router)
  ...
```

For more info take a deep reading into [this tutorial](https://dev.to/pixari/build-a-very-basic-spa-javascript-router-2k4p)

If you have any further doubt comment on this post

Comment: @malarahfelipe It sounds great!! I'm really sorry, but I'm not sure how to implemment it. I did a new file in VS Code named main.js with the code that you share me and I did a reference from index.html... something like `<script src="js/main.js"></script>`. When I execute firebase deploy I can't see any changes, Could you give me please an step by step guide

Comment: @malarahfelipe could you indicate the previous steps? I supposed that your code is to be implemmented in a JS Server. What do I need to implemment it? I just have an index.html that I published and I tryied to implemment a server like your tutorial but it doesn't work. Could you specify exactly what do I need to test your JS Code?

Comment: Hey David, sorry I didn't saw your last message on 25th, gonna try explain now on the following comments

Comment: When you load the file through the script tag, can you see anything doing console.log?
And one thing to mention is, you have to load this script tag after all lib imports ( firebase or any other )

Comment: We can move this conversation to the chat if you like

Comment: Hey Felipe, thank you. I used `npm install -g firebase-tools`. How can we move it to the chat?

Comment: Try enter in here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226889/david-l-firebase-host